# Image not load in imageview using picasso?

Tags: java, android, picasso

In my android project, I am using one fragment , where I stored some value in the shared preference. In the **Homefragment**, I am retrieving that value from **sharedPreference** which is an image url. I am getting the image url correctly from the **sharedPreference** but when I load the image using Picasso, it is not working.

Here's is the code to save data using sharedPreference-

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
    getContext().getSharedPreferences(
        "Profile_PREF", 
        MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit();

editor.putString("user_image", "my image url");
editor.apply();
```

Here's the code I have written for retrieving the image url inside onCreateView-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
    getContext().getSharedPreferences("Profile_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

String restoredImage = prefs.getString("user_image", null);

if(restoredImage != null) {
    userImage = prefs.getString("user_image", null);
}

Log.e("##user_image", userImage);
```

Then after retrieving the image url I have written the following code inside onCreateView for showing the image using Picasso library.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(userImage).into(imageView);
```

But the image is not showing. So, I need a solution for that to show the image.

Comment: in which format you store image in SharedPref ? can you show your "putString()"

Comment: can you post full code of shared preference.

Comment: Please check the edited question

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the image URL in log? And does that image exist in that url path you've provided? Alternatively, try with glide and check if the same problem occurs..

Comment: copy that url and post it in browser, does it open?

Comment: @AkashDubey Yes, I open the url in browse , it is the image which I stored. No problem with that.

Comment: what is your `restoredImage` and `userImage` value after get from sharePrefs ? (you can show on log console.)

Comment: the restoredImage is one temporary variable & userImage is a global variable where I store the image url and in Log I have seen the userImage is getting the correct value

Comment: internet connected or not while loading picture using url with picasso ?

Answer (score 1):

update your picasso library to :

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

now you can find the error in picasso like this:

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(url)
       .fit()
       .error(R.drawable.ic_weight_loss)
       .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

                Log.d("===Adapter","error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });
```